# libva error /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed Electron.js

Tags: electron, ubuntu-20.04

I am new to electron.js and while making a simple desktop app in electron.js I am getting the following warning.

`(node:52973) electron: The default of nativeWindowOpen is deprecated and will be changing from false to true in Electron 15.  See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/28511 for more information. (Use electron --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created) libva error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/iHD_drv_video.so init failed [53016:0909/194957.599483:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(374)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.`

Operating system:- Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: hey, have you found a solution to your problem?